# Any arithmetic circuit of size $s$ and depth $\Delta$ can be converted to a formula of size $s' \leq s^{\Delta}$

Tags: algebraic-complexity, arithmetic-circuits, formulas

I was reading [Ramprasad Saptharishi's survey on Arithmetic Circuits](https://github.com/dasarpmar/lowerbounds-survey/releases/download/v9.0.3/fancymain.pdf).
There in section 2.1.1 fact 2.3 it has

> Any arithmetic circuit of of depth $\Delta$ and size $s$, can be
> simulated by an arithmetic formula of depth $\Delta$  and size $s'\leq
>  s^{\Delta}$

I tried to do this. But i am getting $s^s$ how $s^{\Delta}$ because from node  it can go to at most $s-1$ nodes or gates. So $s^s$.

It is written obviously. But i am failing to find to so. How this result is coming.

Comment: Start from the inputs, induct on depth. If a gate has fan-out more than one, duplicate that gate a number of times equal to its fanout. It's fan-out is at most $s$. So each time you duplicate a layer of gates, you multiply the size by at most $s$. This happens at most depth many times.

Comment: (When you duplicate a gate, you duplicate the entire sub-circuit that feeds into that gate as well.)